# Information and photos of WW2 RAF aircraft and crew?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2

I'm currently researching my uncle's WW2 RAF service and I'm looking for any additional information regarding his Wellington bomber being shot down.

The incident happened on June 9 1941. His plane was a Wellington R1758 from Number 9 Squadron, which was shot down by a Messerschmitt 109 piloted by Staffelkapitän Walter Schneider. My uncle and four other members of the crew bailed out and were picked up and became POWs. The pilot, Roy George Claringbould Arnold, stayed with his plane and died in the North Sea off Zeebrugge.

I'm looking for any data regarding the report of the shooting down, which would have been made by Walter Schneider, photos of him and his aircraft.

Comment: You should post the question about POW records separately.  That way the community can answer, and vote upon, each separately.  Similar questions have already been asked, you may find a search here useful..

Comment: Where do you have your current information from?

Answer (score 7):

This article describes the incident:

http://aircrewremembered.com/roy-arnold.html

and leads me to search for "Oblt Walter Schneider" which comes up with another website or two.

https://airpages.ru/eng/lw/fw190a1_1.shtml
(Fw 190A-1, Werk Nr 027, "Yellow 1" of JG 26, of Oblt Walter Schneider in November 1941, which showed nineteen victory markings on its yellow rudder. He was later killed in a crash after 20 victory.)

It looks like he died on 22 December 1941 when his plane ran into a hillside due to thick fog. Ref: http://www.kagero.eu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=298:focke-wulf-fw-190-vol-ii&catid=95&Itemid=688&limitstart=3